# Auto format and indent code based on the file extension with different formaters in nvim

Tags: vim-plugin, neovim, coc.nvim, nvim-lspconfig

I have a plugin that autosaves the file. This plugin has hooks like .hook_before_saving etc.
Here is an example:

```
local autosave = require("autosave")

autosave.hook_before_saving = function ()
    if <condition> then
        vim.g.auto_save_abort = true -- Save will be aborted
    end
end
```

I would like to use different formaters like prettier for javascript or cargo fmt for rust every time the file is autosaved.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install [Formatter.nvim](https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim) or [null-ls.nvim](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim) Neovim plugin to use different formatters according to filetype (Rust or JS in your case).

And call command to execute code formatting via plugin in your hook for autosave file.

Comment: Thank you. You can see how I did it here https://github.com/Raduc4/Rust-nvim-IDE.git